# How to write a Haskell function that inserts an element into a sorted list

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation

I tried with something like  this but it doesn't work how I wanted it to do. I'm new kinda new to Haskell, and I don't really know how to do it, and what's wrong.

```
 insert a (x:xs) = insert2 a (x:xs) []
            where insert2 el (x:xs) hd =
                    if (x:xs) == [] 
                        then []
                    else if ( a>=x && a < head(xs)) 
                        then hd ++ [x] ++ [a] ++ xs
                    else insert2 a xs hd++[x]
     
    main = do
        let list =[1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6]
        let out = insert 2 list
        print out
```

The output I get is [2,2,3,4,5,6,1]

Comment: `if (x:xs) == []` is equivalent to `if False`, since the list `x:xs` is always non empty. This can't be the correct test. Instead, use two equations, `insert a [] = ...` and `insert a (x:xs) = ...`.

Comment: Take a look at Pattern Guards.You don't need to use if statements nor a secondary helper function at all.

Comment: To add to my comment, I can tell you that your last line `else insert2 a xs hd ++ [x]` appends the element at the front of the list to the end. The predicate `a < head xs` fails in your test case which means you go to that else clause, and will put `1` at the end.

Comment: @DrSooch you meant guards, perhaps.  *pattern* guards is a different, specific thing. (`foo | Just x <- bar = ...`).

Comment: to your specific question "whats wrong?", it's `.... ++[x]` which puts `x` at the end of the overall result, but you took that `x` from the start. so you've _moved_ it from the start to the end. and indeed, look at that `1`.

Comment: @WillNess you would be correct... my fault.

Comment: @DrSooch not a problem, just wanted to disambiguate for the readers, as this is a somewhat common terminology mix-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Prepending to a list is more efficient than appending to one.
2. Haskell lets you write separate definitions to avoid having to write single, nested conditional expressions.

There are two kinds of list you can insert into: empty and non-empty. Each can be handled by a separate definition, which the compiler will use to define a single function.

```
insert a [] = [a]
insert a (x:xs) = ...
```

The first case is easy: inserting into an empty list produces a singleton list. The second case is tricker: what you do depends on whether `a` is smaller than `x` or not. You can use a conditional expression

```
insert a (x:xs) = if a < x then a : insert x xs else x : insert a xs
```

thought you may see guards used instead:

```
insert a (x:xs) | a < x = a : insert x xs
                | otherwise = x : insert a xs
```

In both cases, we know (because the list argument is already sorted) that `insert x xs == x : xs`, so we can write that directly to "short-circuit" the recursion:

```
insert a (x:xs) = if a < x then a : x : xs else x : insert a xs
```

Comment: why bring up `insert x xs` all of a sudden? where does that even come from?

Comment: I was just demonstrating that, conceptually, both cases involve a recursive call. The minimum of `a` and `x` is prepended to the result of the recursive call, and the maximum gets passed as the first argument to the recursive call. Using this approach, there is only one base case.

Comment: no, conceptually, there's no recursion in case `a <= x`. `insert x xs` comes out of nowhere, there's no reason for it, even if `x:xs` _weren't_ sorted -- making the *input* sorted is _not_ the responsibility of the function `insert`.

Answer (score 5):

First a couple of cosmetics:

- Ensure indentation is right. When copy/pasting into StackOverflow, it's generally best to use ctrl+k to get it in code-block style.
- There's no point matching `(x:xs)` only to pass the entire thing into your local function.
- Omit unnecessary parentheses and use standardised spacing.

With that, your code becomes

```
insert a allxs = insert2 a allxs []
 where insert2 el (x:xs) hd =
                if x:xs == [] 
                    then []
                else if a >= x && a < head xs
                    then hd ++ [x] ++ [a] ++ xs
                else insert2 a xs hd ++ [x]
 
main = do
    let list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    let out = insert 2 list
    print out
```

Algorithmically speaking, there's no point in using an “accumulator argument” here. It's easier and actually more efficient to directly recurse on the input, and simply pass on the remaining tail after done with the insertion. Also remember to have a base case:

```
insert a [] = [a]
insert a (x:xs) = ...
```

You also don't need to use `head`. You've already pattern-matched the head element with the `x:xs` pattern. If you did need another list element, you should match that right there too, like

```
insert a (x:x':xs) = ...
```

...but you don't in fact need that, `x` is enough to determine what to do. Namely,

```
insert a (x:xs)
 | a<=x       = -- if the list was ordered, this implies that now _all_
                -- its elements must be greater or equal a. Do you
                -- need any recursion anymore?
 | otherwise  = -- ok, `x` was smaller, so you need to insert after it.
                -- Recursion is needed here.
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some hints. It's a lot simpler than you're making it. You definitely don't need a helper function.

```hs
insert a [] = ??
insert a (x : xs)
  | a <= x = ???
  | otherwise = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

don't complicate! , make simple ...

```
insertme a list = takeWhile (<a) list ++ [a] ++ dropWhile (<a) list
```